# How to organize JS files in a Appcelerator Titanium project

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I have recently started creating an iPhone application using Appcelerator's Titanium. Since the application is essentially all JS, I needed some advice on how I should organize this project.

It's becoming very easy to just create long procedural files for each view in the application. Is there a way I can incorporate MVC, or some structure to the project?

Thanks, I appreciate it.
-Tilo

Comment: While the question remains relevant, note that some of the answers are growing outdated: by now there some patterns which are mentioned in the tutorials and official docs - even the good old sample app KitchenSink (aka king of rats' nests) has been refactored to better reflect current good practice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Titanium itself is essentially MVC given that your app.js file is the main controller and each View you create is the view and you pass (or set) model data against the view.

In Titanium, you can decompose your application using a couple of nice built-in mechanisms:

1. [Titanium.include](https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.include-method.html) - Titanium.include allows you to include one or more JS files in place much like the C `#include` compiler directive.  You can put common functions and JS classes in this file and then include them where ever you want them imported and available.
2. [Titanium.UI.createWindow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.createWindow-method.html) - you can create a new View as as a property of the new Window pass in a URL to another JS context which will create a new JS sub-context and allow you to maintain its own variable space (but still give you access back to your parent).

Also, in Titanium, you can create folders that allow you to logically organize your application in a way that is suitable to you and your application.

**Edit:** Today, the Titanium.Include method is deprecated. 
As mentionned in the documentation, we should create a CommonJS module and use the `require()` statement.

More information about this statement : [Require](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global-method-require)

More information about modules : [Modules](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium)

Comment: I would argue with the statement that

Comment: (please disregard my comment above, I cannot delete it anymore :/)

@jhaynie,

I would argue with the statement that Titanium itself is essentially MVC. When dealing with so-called classic Titanium project, there is almost no structure enforced. Specifically, there are no controllers or models. You can come up with your own structure and make it MVC-like, but classic approach is not MVC per se.

Titanium Alloy (although not released at the time you posted your answer) is an MVC framework, on the other hand. It enforces specific project structure and offers real separation of concerns.

Answer (score 24):

As I was not finding an appropriate MVC solution for a Titanium mobile project, I came up with the following approach. For small apps this might be over-engineered but could help for maintaining growing applications.

Folder structure:

```
/Resources
  /model
  /view
  /controller
  /ui
  /iphone
  /android
  app.js
  app.jss
```

For separating views, models and controllers a namespace is needed, so we define it in the app.js, which is our main controller:

```
var app = {
  view: {},
  controller: {},
  model: {},
  ui: {}
}
```

Within the folders we place single JavaScript files for each component. For this we could either use a lightweight JavaScript OOP library, such as MooTools or Prototype or define simple JS functions as our objects. If you also want to inherit from parent classes, a library definitely makes sense.

Examples:

```
# Resources/controller/MyController.js
app.controller.MyController = function() {
   return {
      getView: function() {
         return new app.view.MyView().getView();
      }
   }
}

# Resources/view/MyView.js
app.view.MyView = function() {
   return {
      getView: function() {
         return Ti.UI.createWindow({...});
      }
   }
}

# Resources/view/MyModel.js
app.model.MyModel = function() {
   return {
      some: "data",
      foo: "bar"
   }
}
```

After that we can include all needed model/view/controller classes with Ti.include() in the app.js file and reference the components with our namespace:

```
Ti.include("controller/MyController.js");
Ti.include("view/MyView.js");
var myController = new app.controller.MyController();
var myView = myController.getView();
myView.open();
```

The MVC approach would now presume that the controller "controls" the state of the view and passes data from the model into the view. The view consists only of UI elements and properties for styling. Any action which is made in the UI fires an event, which tells the controller to perform the desired action.

But of course, the exact definition of MVC might be different according to your personal taste ;)

Comment: like your solution. did it the same way and have made good experiences.

Comment: Like it a lot and would really like to use it. How can I use it in my app?

Comment: I like this. Would the 2014 non-alloy version differ only by the usage of require() instead of Ti.include()?

Comment: For those who are checking it late, `Ti.include()` is Depreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This also may help: A basic struct of how to organize a Titanium mobile project: https://github.com/krawaller/Struct

Comment: Here's a helpful [blog post](http://blog.krawaller.se/titanium-application-structure-learning-from) that explains what is happening in that GitHub repo.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to update this question since most of the responses are superseded. In Q4 2012, Appcelerator released the Alloy MVC (beta) Framework along with the latest IDE and SDK release, Titanium Studio 3.0 and SDK 3.0. Alloy is completely integrated with Studio, so it's quite easy to get a basic app running in less than 15 mins. Alloy introduces a significant folder restructure: The **/app** folder is now where all the development code resides.

The **/Resources** folder, where code used to reside, is now the updated equivalent of the **/build** folder. Compiled code in **/Resources** is overwritten at each build.

I created a short introductory primer (screencast) on creating an Alloy project. You can view it via my dropbox folder.

[Create Alloy Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvduidfkns66khe/create_alloy_project.mov)

Comment: Thank you! You saved me pulling out my hair with this information.

Comment: Is there a way I can split up controller javascript into multiple files so It doesn't have to be one long .js file?

Comment: @JustinVincent you can split your controller files however you like. Just be sure to "require" them in the original container. Also, keep them organized in a way that makes sense to you. If you split code from `foo.js` into `bar.js` and foo needs to know about it, simply add to foo `var bar = require('bar.js')`

Comment: @JustinVincent correction: for the require, it should be `var bar = require('bar');`. Don't add the file extension. Then, in `foo.js`, you can reference bar's code with `bar.doStuff();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Appcelerator made their own [Appcelerator MVC](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/837?1932948971) in the marketplace I have not evaluated this yet.

More Info: http://johnkalberer.com/2011/09/29/appcelerator-mvc-example/